# converting number into two decimal digits in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having this query which show the output as numer number

```
SELECT  rlseamt  FROM ln01mast WHERE acno=214
```

I want to convert it to decimal amount for two digits ex:198.00

Comment: use this http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_number.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Number format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34510) to have desired output.

You can modify your query like this:

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(rlseamt,'999D99')  FROM ln01mast WHERE acno=214
```

You should change the format model acrroding to the the length of NUMBER datatype, defined for rlseamt column. Reason being, if you have values like 1234 in this column, then using the above format model, will not give you correct output, and the output will be replaced by something like `####`. So, you would have to change the format model to `9999D99`

Answer (score 0):

Use this document http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm

You can either use

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(rlseamt,'999D99')  FROM ln01mast WHERE acno=214
```

or

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(rlseamt,'000D00')  FROM ln01mast WHERE acno=214
```

second query will add a starting zero if the numbers before decimal is less than 3 characters.....

Answer (score 0):

Is there another way because I can't to left pad that amount with zeros using this query

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(rlseamt,'9999999999999999999999D99')  FROM ln01mast WHERE acno=214
```